# Using third party controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, graph-sharp

I am pretty new to WPF Developing and i am trying work with the **GraphSharp** lib within my project but I cant access the `GraphSharp.Controls` dll classes.

i declared this row in my mainwindows.xaml file

```
xmlns:gsc = "clr-namespace:GraphSharp.Controls;assembly=GraphSharp.Controls"
```

and when I try to write

```
<gsc:GraphLayout/>
```

Note-GraphLayout is a class that represents a graph in xaml
I tried to look on how to declare namespace in xaml and other resources but couldn't find a good answer for my problem...

Comment: Did you add the reference of the lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to rebuild the solution after adding the GraphSharp lib? In order for the XAML designer/editor to see it, it needs to have the solution rebuilt. Otherwise it will give you an error stating it could not be found.

I just added the GraphSharp lib to a project and was able to use the same namespace you provided, so the namespace is valid.

Also make sure you have added a reference to the GraphSharp library in your project. The best way to do this is via NuGet. Right-Click on your project References and chose to add a new NuGet package. Search for GraphSharp and install it.

Comment: I didn't knew about NuGet so far so u teached me something new :)
Thanks it's working
But i did Rebuilded the solution after adding the DLL

Comment: Glad I was able to help!